# Java Processing Messages Asynchronously in EJB Listener

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, listener, tcp

I have a EJB Singleton that constantly listens for messages as a String and when a message arrives it processes the message for example storing to the database and doing other things.

Once I receive the message and after furthing processing, I need to asycnhrnously send the message. Java provides the ExecuteService to asynchronusly process the message. EJB also provides asynchronously processing through the @Asynchrnous annotation. The listener works by checking every couple of seconds to see if the message has arrived. Once the asynchronous method has been sent, a reply would come back in the form of an InputStream. I have two queries:

I have sample code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Processor {

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
          while(true) {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              if(!portIsOpen()) {
                 openPort();
                 listen();
              }
              else {
                 listen();
              }
          }
     }

     public void listen() {
        // listens for messages, once the message arrives process them and then send asynchronously
         Future<InputStream> inputStream = processAsynchrnously();
         while(!inputStream.isDone()) {
             // carry on with repeated requests
         }
         inputStream = inputStream.get();
         // read this inputStream and turn into XML
     }

     @Asynchronous
     public Future<InputStream> processAsynchronosly() {
         // make an http connection and send the request of with the data as XML
         return new AsychResult<InputStream>(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());
     }
}
```

The above is what I am trying to achive. However, the aim is to send the request asynchrnously and not wait but continue to receive other requests repeatly. The problem is the while(!inputStream.isDone()) this means it is blocked.

1) How can this be implemented in a different way so the while loop is not required.

2) When the data is available so the input stream is returned with the XML, in EJB is there a listener that can be invoked so that I will implement a method that will read the contents of the input stream? I am aware there are Inceptors but an Inceptor will not work in this case.

EDIT:

Please note the application is a TCIIP application, so it listens for messages on a port. It is not a RMI-IIOP application. This Singleton acts as a listener, so when the message arrives it processes it.

If MDB is the only solution how will MDB help? Could you show a code sample?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using MDBs?

Comment: How can MDB be used in this scenerio? I was thinking of JMS. Please could you give me an example of how MDB will solve my problem?

Comment: You will need to setup JMS queue/topic in your application server. Then you will need to point your MDB to the queue/topic. There are plenty of tutorials online. I found this link helpful http://j2eearchitec.blogspot.in/2012/11/ejb-30-message-driven-bean-and-jms.html

Comment: The problem is how will MDB will solve the asynchrnously problem with the while(!inputStream.isDone()) problem. What I mean I expect a response back from the Http call, so how can MDB solve the problem of this?

Comment: MDBs are inherently asynchronous by nature. The app server maintains a pool of MDBs and assign an available MDB to each and every message. Multiple MDBs can work in parallel. So when one of message is being processed, other messages will not wait for that to finish.

Comment: So does that mean, one Http request is sent the code placed above while(!inputStream.isDone()) { } inputStream = inputStream.get() will work and when another request is sent through another MDB will be specically allocated? If yes, does the Application Server automatically configure number of MDBs or if for example there are 110 messages then 110 MDBs will be generated?

Comment: Yes. You dont need to write any code for asynchronous handling. Just write whatever logic in your MDB. App server will invoke the MDBs parallely for different messages.